# Can do I condense this code for making multiple labels and entries depending on a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a scale to select how many players there are, then by pressing a button, it sends you to the page where you input the names of each player, of which they are put into a list for later use.

The problem is, it takes up loads of space and I feel like there is most definitely a way to condense this.

```
def playerset():
    title.configure(text="Set amount of players:", font=("Arial", 20))
    eir.grid_remove()
    pit.grid_remove()
    playerbut.grid_remove()
    player = IntVar()
    playerscale = Scale(window, from_=1, to=12, width=30, length=300, orient=HORIZONTAL, variable=player)
    playerscale.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def playernext():
        players=int(player.get())
        title.configure(text="Name each player:", font=("Arial", 20))
        playernextbut.grid_forget()
        playerscale.grid_forget()
        if (players > 0):
            player1dis = Label(window, text="Player 1", font=("Arial", 15))
            player1dis.grid(column=0, row=1)
            player1 = StringVar()
            p1 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player1, font=("Arial", 15))
            p1.grid(column=1, row=1)
            if (players > 1):
                player2dis = Label(window, text="Player 2", font=("Arial", 15))
                player2dis.grid(column=0, row=2)
                player2 = StringVar()
                p2 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player2, font=("Arial", 15))
                p2.grid(column=1, row=2)
                if (players > 2):
                    player3dis = Label(window, text="Player 3", font=("Arial", 15))
                    player3dis.grid(column=0, row=3)
                    player3 = StringVar()
                    p3 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player3, font=("Arial", 15))
                    p3.grid(column=1, row=3)
                    if (players > 3):
                        player4dis = Label(window, text="Player 4", font=("Arial", 15))
                        player4dis.grid(column=0, row=4)
                        player4 = StringVar()
                        p4 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player4, font=("Arial", 15))
                        p4.grid(column=1, row=4)
                        if (players > 4):
                            player5dis = Label(window, text="Player 5", font=("Arial", 15))
                            player5dis.grid(column=0, row=5)
                            player5 = StringVar()
                            p5 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player5, font=("Arial", 15))
                            p5.grid(column=1, row=5)
                            if (players > 5):
                                player6dis = Label(window, text="Player 6", font=("Arial", 15))
                                player6dis.grid(column=0, row=6)
                                player6 = StringVar()
                                p6 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player6, font=("Arial", 15))
                                p6.grid(column=1, row=6)
                                if (players > 6):
                                    player7dis = Label(window, text="Player 7", font=("Arial", 15))
                                    player7dis.grid(column=0, row=7)
                                    player7 = StringVar()
                                    p7 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player7, font=("Arial", 15))
                                    p7.grid(column=1, row=7)
                                    if (players > 7):
                                        player8dis = Label(window, text="Player 8", font=("Arial", 15))
                                        player8dis.grid(column=0, row=8)
                                        player8 = StringVar()
                                        p8 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player8, font=("Arial", 15))
                                        p8.grid(column=1, row=8)
                                        if (players > 8):
                                            player9dis = Label(window, text="Player 9", font=("Arial", 15))
                                            player9dis.grid(column=0, row=9)
                                            player9 = StringVar()
                                            p9 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player9, font=("Arial", 15))
                                            p9.grid(column=1, row=9)
                                            if (players > 9):
                                                player10dis = Label(window, text="Player 10", font=("Arial", 15))
                                                player10dis.grid(column=0, row=10)
                                                player10 = StringVar()
                                                p10 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player10, font=("Arial", 15))
                                                p10.grid(column=1, row=10)
                                                if (players > 10):
                                                    player11dis = Label(window, text="Player 11", font=("Arial", 15))
                                                    player11dis.grid(column=0, row=11)
                                                    player11 = StringVar()
                                                    p11 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player11, font=("Arial", 15))
                                                    p11.grid(column=1, row=11)
                                                    if (players > 11):
                                                        player12dis = Label(window, text="Player 12", font=("Arial", 15))
                                                        player12dis.grid(column=0, row=12)
                                                        player12 = StringVar()
                                                        p12 = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable=player12, font=("Arial", 15))
                                                        p12.grid(column=1, row=12)

        def playersubmit():
            title.configure(text="-----Welcome to the Rottot Games Interface!-----", font=("Arial", 30))
            eir.grid()
            pit.grid()
            playerbut.grid()
            playersubmitbut.grid_forget()
            if (players > 0):
                p1name=str(player1.get())
                plist = [p1name]
                player1dis.grid_forget()
                p1.grid_forget()
                if (players > 1):
                    p2name=str(player2.get())
                    plist = [p1name, p2name]
                    player2dis.grid_forget()
                    p2.grid_forget()
                    if (players > 2):
                        p3name=str(player3.get())
                        plist = [p1name, p2name, p3name]
                        player3dis.grid_forget()
                        p3.grid_forget()
                        if (players > 3):
                            p4name=str(player4.get())
                            plist = [p1name, p2name, p3name, p4name]
                            player4dis.grid_forget()
                            p4.grid_forget()
                            if (players > 4):
                                p5name=str(player5.get())
                                plist = [p1name, p2name, p3name, p4name, p5name]
                                player5dis.grid_forget()
                                p5.grid_forget()
                                if (players > 5):
                                    p6name=str(player6.get())
                                    plist = [p1name, p2name, p3name, p4name, p5name, p6name]
                                    player6dis.grid_forget()
                                    p6.grid_forget()
                                    if (players > 6):
                                        p7name=str(player7.get())
                                        plist = [p1name, p2name, p3name, p4name, p5name, p6name, p7name]
                                        player7dis.grid_forget()
                                        p7.grid_forget()
                                        if (players > 7):
                                            p8name=str(player8.get())
                                            plist = [p1name, p2name, p3name, p4name, p5name, p6name, p7name, p8name]
                                            player8dis.grid_forget()
                                            p8.grid_forget()
                                            if (players > 8):
                                                p9name=str(player9.get())
                                                plist = [p1name, p2name, p3name, p4name, p5name, p6name, p7name, p8name, p9name]
                                                player9dis.grid_forget()
                                                p9.grid_forget()
                                                if (players > 9):
                                                    p10name=str(player10.get())
                                                    plist = [p1name, p2name, p3name, p4name, p5name, p6name, p7name, p8name, p9name, p10name]
                                                    player10dis.grid_forget()
                                                    p10.grid_forget()
                                                    if (players > 10):
                                                        p11name=str(player11.get())
                                                        plist = [p1name, p2name, p3name, p4name, p5name, p6name, p7name, p8name, p9name, p10name, p11name]
                                                        player11dis.grid_forget()
                                                        p11.grid_forget()
                                                        if (players > 11):
                                                            p12name=str(player12.get())
                                                            plist = [p1name, p2name, p3name, p4name, p5name, p6name, p7name, p8name, p9name, p10name, p11name, p12name]
                                                            player12dis.grid_forget()
                                                            p12.grid_forget()

            import pickle
            with open("Players.txt", "wb") as playersave:
                pickle.dump(plist, playersave)

        playersubmitbut = Button(window, text="Submit", command=playersubmit, font=("Arial", 15), bg="green", fg="black")
        playersubmitbut.grid(column=4, row=0)

    playernextbut = Button(window, text="Next", command=playernext, font=("Arial", 20), bg="green", fg="black")
    playernextbut.grid(column=4, row=1)

playerbut = Button(window, text="Set Players", command=playerset, font=("Arial", 20), bg="gray", fg="black")
playerbut.grid(column=1, row=2)
```

Apologies for all the code, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without going into the tkinter specifics too much, it looks like this can be done with a loop and a dictionary.

A more robust approach could be to use a class for a Player, that would store all the relevant information.

Example below includes the player name and the playerdis label, but not anything else. You can expand it to include any information/widget you need to keep track of.

```python
def playerset():

    ### CONFIG STUFF HERE ###

    def playernext():
        players=int(player.get())
        ### CONFIG STUFF ### 
        player_info = {} # dictionary of dictionaries to store references to stringvars, pidsgrids etc for each player id
        for player_index in range(players):
            playerdis = Label(window, text="Player "+str(player_index)) # change formatting as necessary
            player_info[player_index] = {}  # make an empty subdictionary for this player
            player_info[player_index]['label'] = playerdis  # store reference to the label
            player_info[player_index]['name'] = StringVar() # store reference to the stringvar
            name_entry = Entry(window, width=20, textvariable= player_info[player_index]['name'])

            ### MORE CONFIG STUFF ###   
    return player_info  # return the populated dictionary of references for later use
```

And then further down when you need to use this information:

```python
def playersubmit(player_info):
            ### CONFIG STUFF ###
            playersubmitbut.grid_forget()
            for player_index in player_info.keys():
                pname=str(player_info[player_index]['name'].get()) # get the name from the StringVar reference
                plist = [pname]
                player_info[player_index]['label'].grid_forget()  # access the label and forget
                ### CONFIG STUFF ###
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes to modularize your code, and deal with specialized small entities that do one thing well:

Maybe a class `Player` to hold the info relevant to a player, a class `Players` to hold a collection of players?

Your `App` code can also be modularized: The following toy example has a main `App` that has 3 buttons that control the pop of a `Toplevel` window to enter the number of players, another to enter the specifics of each player, and lastly, one that prints the players in the collection.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Player:
    """Represents a Player in the game
    """
    ID = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.id = self.make_id()

    def make_id(self):
        Player.ID += 1
        return Player.ID - 1

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Player {self.id}, {self.name}'


class Players:
    """A collection of Players
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.players = []

    def add_player(self, player):
        self.players.append(player)

    def __iter__(self):
        for player in self.players:
            yield player

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.players)


class App(tk.Tk):
    """The app itself
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.players = Players()
        self.num_players = 0
        tk.Button(self, text='get number of players', command = self.get_num_players).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='build a players', command = self.build_players).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='print list players', command=lambda: print(str(self))).pack()

    def get_num_players(self):
        NumPlayerEntry(self)

    def build_players(self):
        if len(self.players) < self.num_players:
            PlayerBuilder(self)

    def __str__(self):
        res = []
        for player in self.players:
            res.append(str(player))
        return '\n'.join(res)


class NumPlayerEntry(tk.Toplevel):
    """popup that allows to enter the number of players in the game
    """

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(master)
        tk.Label(self, text='enter number of players').pack()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='confirm', command=self.confirm_num_players).pack()

    def confirm_num_players(self):
        self.master.num_players = int(self.entry.get())
        self.destroy()


class PlayerBuilder(tk.Toplevel):
    """popup that allows to enter the characteristics of a player
    """

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(master)
        tk.Label(self, text='add player (enter name)').pack()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='confirm', command=self.make_player).pack()

    def make_player(self):
        self.master.players.add_player(Player(self.entry.get()))
        self.destroy()


App().mainloop()
```